# Как найти количество и позицию символа в строке (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, angularjs

Есть вот такие строки (или массив объектов) из 96 символов:

```
1. 000000000000000000000011111111111111100000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111
2. 000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111000000001111111111111111111111110000000000000000
3. 000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111110000000222222222222222200000000000
```

Может быть только 3 символа: 0, 1, 2, мне нужно найти количество и позицию каждой группы символов, например:

```
var str = '000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111110000000222222222222222200000000000';
```

Что должно получиться:

```
zero: [
    {
        startPos: 0,
        count: 33
    }, {
        startPos: 63,
        count: 7
    }, {
        startPos: 86,
        count: 11
    }
],
one: [
    {
        startPos: 33,
        count: 30
    }
],
two: [
    {
        startPos: 70,
        count: 16
    }
]
```

Comment: Решение: [https://toster.ru/q/361456](https://toster.ru/q/361456)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var s = "000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111110000000222222222222222200000000000"
var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two']
var res = {}
names.forEach(n => res[n] = [])
s.replace(/(.)\1*/g, (m,ch,i) => res[names[ch]].push({startPos: i, count: m.length}))
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, '  '))
```